# Drawing widgets on existing sdl_opengl context

Tags: sdl, fltk, sdl-opengl

Is there any actively developed open-source (GPL is fine) library that can draw widgets such as buttons, menus, etc on an existing SDL/OpenGL context? I have heard of FLTK, but it appears that it creates its own window and its own OpenGL context to draw widgets on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [CeGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is perfectly capable of drawing into an OpenGL context (it doesn't care how you initialize OpenGL).

Comment: _Really_ messy library. But it seems to do what it claims to do